# When I dispatch, payload(value) goes back to old value in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

```js
// EditableNote.js
function EditableNote({ note }) {
    const [editableNote, setEditableNote] = useState(note);
    const { title, content } = editableNote;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        setEditableNote(note);
    }, [note]);
›
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(saveEditableNote(editableNote));   // I think here is problem
    }, [dispatch, editableNote]);

    const handleBlur = e => {
        const name = e.target.id;
        const value = e.currentTarget.textContent;
        setEditableNote({ ...editableNote, [name]: value });
    };

    return (
        <EditNote spellCheck="true">
            <NoteTitle
                id="title"
                placeholder="Title"
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                contentEditable
                suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
                {title}
            </NoteTitle>
            <NoteContent
                id="content"
                placeholder="Note"
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                contentEditable
                suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
                {content}
            </NoteContent>
        </EditNote>
    );
}

export default EditableNote;
```

I have EditableNote component which is contentEditable. I set its initial state through props from its parent(Note). So if something is changed in note, then editableNote has to changed.
To keep recent props state, I use useEffect. Everything seems working well.

Here is an issue. If I first change color of note and typing, it is updated as expected. But on contrast, if I first typing and change color, editableNote state is not updated.

```
// Reducer.js
 case actions.GET_NOTE_COLOR: 
            return {                
                ...state,
                bgColor: action.payload
            }
        case actions.CHANGE_NOTE_COLOR: 
            return {                    
                ...state,
                notes: state.notes.map(note => note.id === action.payload ? 
                    { ...note, bgColor: state.bgColor } 
                    : note       
                )
            };
        case actions.SAVE_EDITABLE_NOTE: // payload is old value
            return { 
                ...state,
                editableNote: action.payload,
            }
```

I check what happened in an action. I found everything works until CHANGE_NOTE_COLOR but when dispatch SAVE_EDITABLE_NOTE, its payload is not updated!

I have no idea.. plz.. help me...TT

Comment: Can you setup a Codesandbox?

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/note-kz006?file=/src/containers/Notes/EditableNote/EditableNote.js) Here is my codesnadbox..

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `connect` wrapper provided by `redux` to connect `actions` and `state` of redux to your components
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: Thank you! But my component is functional.. So I connected using hooks like useSelector and useDispatch.